# Project Reactor - Does Mono/Flux Zip method run code in parallel & how to handle Void return type?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to confirm 2 things.

One, that zipping a collection of Monos or Fluxes will in fact run blocking-type calls such as hitting API endpoints, DB calls, or other network-related calls in a non-blocking context in parallel.

```
Mono<A> a = myDatabaseCall();
Mono<B> b = myAPICall();
Mono<C> c = myBlockingCall();

// Code I would like to be executed in parallel (at the same time)
Mono.zip(a, b, c)
```

Two, how to run a parallel call when the return type of 1 call is `Mono<Void>` & for the other calls are non-void.

```
Mono<A> a = myDatabaseCall();
Mono<Void> b = notifySystem();

// How would you run in parallel since, Mono.zip doesn't support Void? Use Flux.zip?
Mono.zip(a, b)
```

Also, I am not super familiar the methods `fromCallable()` or `subscribeOn` & I was curious to know if anyone knew if this scenario would be a use case for them?

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> myDatabaseCall())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());  // or Schedulers.parallel() ?
```

Comment: In general it runs them in parallel (i.e., subscribe to all at the same time), but you may use `subscribeOn` to make sure it doesn't do everything in the current subscription thread. `boundedElastic` is a right choice for IO

Comment: @IgorArtamonov If I am wanting to run them in parallel then, there is no need to use `subscribeOn` since, that would more so be if I want certain calls to be subscribed at different points in time correct ?

Comment: Some _Publishers_ may execute too many operations, if not everything, during the subscription itself. I.e., it takes a bit longer to subscribe. So without `subscribeOn` you will subscribe to them one by one in the same thread. Not a big problem maybe if the publishers are actually use their own thread for publishing. Latter is not always the case, and some may continue the processing in the same thread as they received the subscription command, which forces the following _subscription_ calls to wait for the current one. With `subscribeOn` you always switch to a new thread to avoid that